# Can not add foreign key on column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Can somebody tell me why is not possible add foreign key on this column definition. First is the primary key, second should be foreign key to first one:

```
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;

`geis_point_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Both are int(11), not unsigned and indexed. MySQL version is 5.7.21. PhpMyAdmin does not show the reason why. Only stupid notice... I dont know if it could be the NULLable part of the geis_point_id. But I already have some rows in the table, which should be NULL.

Comment: Are storage engine the same? Or do you get error like value does not exist in "parent" table?

Comment: Show us both CREATE TABLE statements. (Remove unrelated stuff if they are big.)

Comment: lad2025 YES thats it. Engine was MyISAM/InnoDB. So I change it and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Please add the `CREATE TABLE` statements. Also add the SQL foreign key constraint definition. Please don't reply "I clicked here, then there, and ...". Show some real SQL.